# How to known a function of a interface is not realized?

Tags: go, panic

I just tried the following code in Go.

```golang
package main

type inter interface {
    aaa() int
}

type impl struct {
    inter
}

func main() {
    var a inter
    a = impl{}
    // how to check the function for interface `inter` is not realized?
    a.aaa()
}
```

It can be `go build` and `go run`. But will receive a panic like:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0x8972c]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.(*impl).aaa(0x40c018, 0x41a788, 0xb2ae0, 0x40c018)
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x2c
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox029518300/prog.go:15 +0x60
```

How can I know the `a.aaa()` is not realized.

Comment: But the type of `a` is `inter`. There is none attribute `inter` of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `a` is of type `inter`, an interface, which is pointing to an `impl`. The struct `impl` has the `inter` interface embedded in it. That means `impl.aaa()` exists, which actually means `impl.inter.aaa()`. However in your code `impl.inter` is nil. To make it more clear:

```
b:=impl{}
var a inter
a=b
a.aaa() // this will call b.inter.aaa(), but b.inter is nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the only way to avoid the panic for the situation is to check the `Type` of `inter`?

Comment: @lzmhhh123, no, you just have to initialize your struct correctly. Don't leave the inter field nil.